# Apache (apache2) HTTP server stops accepting connections after a while and requires restart

Tags: sockets, http, apache2, apache2.4

The apache server uses up all of the servers (up to ServerLimit) and then does not accept any more connections.

```
Slot PID    Stopping    Connections     Threads Async connections
                      total accepting busy    idle  writing keep-alive   closing
 0  23257   yes       1         no     0         0       0        0           0
 1  27271   no        0         yes    1        24       0        0           0
 2  24876   yes       2         no     0         0       0        0           0
 3  23117   yes       2         no     0         0       0        0           0
 4  22671   yes       1         no     0         0       0        0           0
 5  23994   yes       1         no     0         0       0        0           0
 6  25159   yes       1         no     0         0       0        0           0
 7  24604   yes       1         no     0         0       0        0           0
 Sum 8       7        9                1        24       0        0           0
```

The one pid that was accepting was killed and restarted to get the status report  above.  Over time this PID would also end up like the rest.  How do I find out why Apache stops accepting connections after a while?  The timeout is set at 90 seconds.

Additional information:

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2o
Server Built: Apr 18 2018 10:56:21
Server loaded APR Version: 1.6.3
Compiled with APR Version: 1.6.3
Server loaded APU Version: 1.6.1
Compiled with APU Version: 1.6.1
Module Magic Number: 20120211:76
Hostname/port: localhost:8006
Timeouts: connection: 90    keep-alive: 5
MPM Name: event
MPM Information: Max Daemons: 8 Threaded: yes Forked: yes
Server Architecture: 64-bit
```

Comment: same question here :( .. why does it keep one or more connection (total) on graceful stop sitting for minutes (and eventually till all slots "stuffed"), even if no connection is used (busy/idle/writ/keep/close) ? .. workaround for me is currently raising the max connections per child and threads per child.. so one slot can handle more requests before stopping

Comment: also it would help to know your mpm_event.conf settings ;)

Comment: mpm_event_config is the default setting.  I have adjusted it and like you said it only changes how quickly (for lower values) I need to recycle. One workaround is probably to set a very low value for MaxConnectionsPerChild so they auto recycle.